# Communication with user from an android service

Tags: android, user-interface, service, communication

Is there any way to communicate with user from an android service?

It is important in cases where user have to accept something (access to sms, contacts, reading Spreadsheets, etc.) or log in using OAuth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use bound service. Extend [Binder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html) for that.

You can use although [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) service, but it should be used in 2 cases:

1. If you are running out of memory, or you need isolate service from main process, and will locate service in another linux process (process=":service_proc_name" in manifest and it will be another pid).
   Be carefull, Debugger will not start on this process automatically.
2. If you provide access to your service from another app.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks!